# Twilio "Invalid TLS protocol" error using C# helper library

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am unable to invoke Twilio api functions. I know Twilio has upgraded their security and I have got the email for same in past and I have gone through the upgrade.
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006751753-Tips-for-Upgrading-Your-Environment-to-Support-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Strong-Cipher-Suite-Changes

My production environment is updated and I am able to get an xml result when hitting the url: https://api.twilio.com:8443 from my production environment browser. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226478767-Monitoring-Updates-to-Twilio-REST-API-Security-Settings says **"If your HTTP request succeeds, no changes will be needed on your end for the update."**

However in the process, I also updated the Twilio C# api (.Net Framework 4.6.1) (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio). Even after all the steps and tests I am still getting "Invalid TLS protocol" error using following code:

```
public string sentToday()
        {
            string sTotalTodaysRecord = "0";
            string AccountId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountId"];
            string AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthToken"];
            TwilioClient.Init(AccountId, AuthToken);
            var records = TodayResource.Read();
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                sTotalTodaysRecord = record.Count;
                break;
            }
            return sTotalTodaysRecord;
        }

TwilioClient.Init(AccountId, AuthToken); // this part throws the exception "Invalid TLS Protocol"
```

Twilio updated their security during 2019-2020 and we updated our production server back then. Also we were able to send SMSes using Twilio till recently so why it suddenly stopped working.

**Update:**

Specifying the security protocol works resolves the tls protocol issue

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

As mentioned in : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006751753-Tips-for-Upgrading-Your-Environment-to-Support-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Strong-Cipher-Suite-Changes

But still not receiving smses as I believe references in the code are old:

> Inner Exception: Method not found:
> 'Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageResource
> Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageResource.Create(Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber,
> System.String, Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber, System.String, System.String,
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1, System.Uri, System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.Nullable`1, System.Nullable`1,
> System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.String, ContentRetentionEnum, AddressRetentionEnum, System.Nullable`1,
> Twilio.Clients.ITwilioRestClient)'.

Comment: Assuming the client is a nuget package, have you tried updating the client?

Comment: Which exact version and build number of Windows do you have? You should upgrade to .Net 4.7.1 at a minimum.

Comment: What is the code you are using to send SMS messages?